# Security Update 2015-002 Asks To Setup Mac

Tags: macos, security, software-update

I just had to install the latest Security Update from the Mac App Store and it started auto updating.
[image]

Then when I completed the update (and restarted) my Mac asked me to enter in my Apple ID password and asked me if I would like the 'Cloud keychain thing', after that it said it was setting up my mac (***just like the first installation!***) it did however keep all my data.

Is this normal for the latest update or do I have some sort of virus?

**Edit**

Here are the latest updates on my Mac
[image]

Comment: When did the message appear? Was it during the restart? If so, Safari could have just been giving you the beach ball of death or otherwise refusing to automatically quit.

Comment: In you title you say "Security Update 18/03/15" and the latest is, Security Update 2015-002 Post Date: Mar 9, 2015, so if you have an update that's dated today it's not from Apple.

Comment: @user3439894 it was Security Update 2015-002 Post Date. Think it was slow updating.

Comment: @user24601 It was before the update could install. My Mac updated the software as soon as safari was closed. I also read on Mac rumors that there was a update for Safari

Comment: Also, what does "it started auto updating" mean? What exactly happened?

Comment: I had auto updates turned on (forgot about that) and so my computer started to update safari and the security update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is normal for iCloud tokens to time out. You will see it when you reboot, so the update was a coincidence and not causing the password request.

This setup seems to trigger more often if one of your user accounts on the Mac uses an iCloud password for the account or you have Back to my Mac or Find my Mac enabled in iCloud system preference pane.

Comment: So do you mean that the iCloud token caused the 'Setup My Mac' to appear?

Comment: @iProgram Yes - if you open your keychain, you can see that things have an expiration date. I believe that internally, there is an intermediate certificate with an even shorter expiration date and/or some ability of server side to request reauthorizations if there's confusion about what IP address you are using to access services. Anti fraud, etc...

Comment: I do bring mine to college so my IP address will change. This may be what is happening.